# Ayuda con el error: cannot call getOutputStream() after getWriter(), al intentar realizar una descarga de archivo en java?

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring, csv

Tengo el siguiente método en el controller, el cual regresa un respuesta tipo json a la vista, para mostrar en un dialogo si hay o no datos en la bd de acuerdo a la informacion de los parámetros que le paso a mi servicio.

```html
 
@RequestMapping(value="view/obtieneInfo")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@ResponseBody
public  JsonResponse obtieneInfor(@ResponseBody Factura fact, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse respons) throws ControlException{

JsonResponse response = new JsonResponse();
response.setExito(0);
response.setDatos(null);

try{
List<Factura> factList = obtieneInfoService.consultaDatos(id, cvePag, fecha);
if(factList !=null && !factList.isEmpty){
 response.setExito(1);
 response.setDatos(factList);

}else{
  log.info("Esta vacio");
}
}catch(ControlException e){
   throw new ControlException("Error", e);
}
return response;
}
```

Este es mi código de la vista, el cual valida campos y cuando se llenan los campos y se da click en el boton, se le pasan esos parámetros al servicio, y manda un dialogo para informar si hay o no datos, y si los hay que descargue un archivo con esos datos

```html
<script>

function consultar(){
var valido = true;
var valId = document.getElementaryById('idPago').value;
var valClavePago = document.getElementaryById('clavePago').value;
var valFecha = document.getElementaryById('fechaPago').value;

if(valId.trim() =="" && valClavePago.trim() == "" && valFecha.trim() == ""){

  HelperDialogs.mostrar("Debes ingresar al menos un valor");
  valido = false;
}
  return valido;
}



function obtieneInf(){
 if(consultar()){
  if(!HelperForm.valido(consulta, validator)){
   return;
   
  }else{
   
   var data = Helper.obtenerJsonForm(consulta);
   var url="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/view/obtieneInfo";
   $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    url: url,
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
   success: function(response){
    if(response.exito==1){
     HelperDialogo.mostrar("Si hay registros");
    }else{
     HelperDialogo.mostrar("No se encontraron registros");
    }

   },
   error: function(response){
    HelperDialogo.mostrarError(response);
   }

   });
  }
 }
}
</script>
<form:form id="consulta" modelAttribute="consultaForm">
  <tr>
    <td><label>ID/label></td>
    <td><form: input type="text"  id="idPago" path="id"/></td>
   </tr>
   
   <tr>
    <td><label>CLAVE PAGO</label></td>
    <td><form: input type="text" id="clavePago" path="clavePago"/></td>
   </tr>
   
   <tr>
   
   
   <tr>
    <td><label>FECHA PAGO</label></td>
    <td><form: input type="text" id="fechaPago" path="fechaPago"/></td>
    <input type="button" onclick="obtieneInf()"></input>
   </tr>
</form:form>
```

Y lo hace de forma correcta, el problema se presenta  al momento de agregarle el código para que realice la descarga de un archivo con la informacion que regresa 
la consulta, el código queda así:

```html
@RequestMapping(value="view/obtieneInfo")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@ResponseBody
public  JsonResponse obtieneInfor(@ResponseBody Factura fact, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse respons) throws ControlException{

JsonResponse response = new JsonResponse();
response.setExito(0);
response.setDatos(null);

try{
List<Factura> factList = obtieneInfoService.consultaDatos(id, cvePag, fecha);
if(factList !=null && !factList.isEmpty){
 response.setExito(1);
 response.setDatos(factList);
 
 response.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/csv");
 response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=archivo.csv");
 
 PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
   out.write("columna1,columna2,columna3");
   out.write("\n");
   
   for(Factura factu: factList){
    out.write(factu.toCSVRepresentation());
    out.write("\n");
   }
    out.flush();
    out.close();

}else{
  log.info("Esta vacio");
}
}catch(ControlException e){
   throw new ControlException("Error", e);
}
return response;
}
```

y manda ese error: servlet API cannot call getOutputStream() after getWriter()

a que se debe ese error?, que me hace falta?
y es que ademas, si hago la descarga del archivo en este mismo método ,este va a contener todo el html de la pagina, y la informacion de la consulta

entonces mejor borre el código de la descarga del archivo en el metodo json, y agregue otro  método igual al anterior, pero void, y así el archivo ya no contiene todo el html de la pagina, pero no recoge los datos de los input, los deja como null y pues no hace nada

Este es el nuevo método que agregue, pero no recoge los datos de los input, y me manda mensaje de que no hay datos, por que estan nullos, ademas pues estaría repitiendo código, como le puedo hacer?, o cual es la manera correcta de hacer la descarga del archivo?

```html
@RequestMapping(value="view/obtieneArchivo")
public  void obtieneArchivo(@ResponseBody Factura fact, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ControlException{

try{
List<Factura> factList = obtieneInfoService.consultaDatos(id, cvePag, fecha);
if(factList !=null && !factList.isEmpty){
 
 response.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/csv");
 response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=archivo.csv");
 
 PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
   out.write("columna1,columna2,columna3");
   out.write("\n");
   
   for(Factura factu: factList){
    out.write(factu.toCSVRepresentation());
    out.write("\n");
   }
    out.flush();
    out.close();

}else{
  log.info("Esta vacio");
}
}catch(ControlException e){
   throw new ControlException("Error", e);
}
}
```

y agregue esta funcion a mi jsp

```html
function descargaArchivo(){
 
 var url="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/view/obtieneArchivo";
 $.fileDownload(url)
   .done(
     function(){
   Helper.muestraInf("Se descargo correctamente");
  }
   
   )
 .fail(
  function(){
   Helper.muestraInf("Ocurrio un  error en la descarga");
  }
 );
}
```

Ojala me puedan ayudar, apenas empiezo con esto y no entiendo muchas cosas, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Primero, se agradece que pongas la información necesaria para la pregunta -sobre todo en comparación con otras preguntas que hay por aquí-. Pero te has pasado. Solo el tercer fragmento de código y la explicación posterior son relevantes. Y no tiene nada que ver con Javascript.

Por otra parte, suele ser conveniente incluir el *stacktrace* de la excepción lanzada e indicar la línea donde se lanza, si es en tu código.

En cuanto al error, viendo el mensaje vamos a la documentación de [HttpServletResponse](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html) que nos indica que el método `getWriter()` se hereda de [ServletResponse](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html). En la documentación de [getWriter()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getOutputStream()) nos pone:

> Either this method or getWriter() may be called to write the body, not both.

Tu código no llama a `getOutputStream()`, pero devuelve una estructura para que el API JSON genera la respuesta. El API JSON llama a `getOutputStream` para escribir sus datos en el `response` y allí lanza la excepción.

Lo cual es una suerte, porque si no, no te habría fallado pero recibirías una respuesta que es parte tu archivo de texto y parte JSON.

El segundo intento que haces<sup>1</sup> no encuentra las variables porque simplemente no le envías ninguna información JSON (no hay elemento `data`); puedes hacer la petición simplemente mediante una petición GET normal y corriente

```
url = '.../view/obtieneArchivo&id=' + id + '&clavePago=' + clavePago + '&fecha=' + fecha;
```

y en el controlador obtener los valores mediante `request.getParameter()`<sup>2</sup>.

Otra opción es sencillamente hacer que el `form` tenga como `action` un servlet que generará el fichero.

---

<sup>1</sup> Por favor, una pregunta/versión por pregunta aquí.

<sup>2</sup> Según el formato, puede ser necesario codificar la fecha con `encodeURIComponent` para obtener una URL válida.